# Hive on Spark list all partitions for specific hive table and adding a partition

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am using spark 2.0 and I was wondering ,Is it possible to list all files for specific hive table? If so, I can incrementally update those files directly using spark `sc.textFile("file.orc")`
.
How can I add a new partition to hive table? is there any api on the hive metastore that I can use from spark?

Is there any way to get the internal hive function that map dataframe `row => partition_path`

my main reasoning is incremental updates for a table. right now the only way I have figured out is `FULL OUTER JOIN` SQL +`SaveMode.Overwrite`, which is not so efficient because he will overwrite  all the table while my main interest is incremental updates for some specific partitions/adding new partition

**EDIT**
from what I have saw on the HDFS, when SaveMode.Overwrite spark will emit the table definition i.e `CREATE TABLE my_table .... PARTITION BY (month,..)`. spark is putting all files under the `$HIVE/my_table` and not under `$HIVE/my_table/month/...` which means he is not partitioning the data. when I wrote `df.write.partitionBy(...).mode(Overwrite).saveAsTable("my_table")` I have saw on hdfs that it is correct. 
I have used `SaveMode.Overwrite` because I am updating records and not appending data.

I load data using `spark.table("my_table")` which means spark lazily load the table which is a problem since I don't want to load all the table just part of if.

for the question:

1.Does spark going to shuffle the data because I have used `partitionBy()` ,or he compares current partition and if its the same he will not shuffle the data.

2.Does spark smart enough to use partition pruning when mutating part from the data i.e just for specific month/year, and apply that change instead of loading all the data? (FULL OUTER JOIN is basically operation that scan all the table)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Adding partitions:**

Adding partition from spark can be done with [`partitionBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#partitionBy(scala.collection.Seq)) provided in `DataFrameWriter` for non-streamed or with `DataStreamWriter` for streamed data.

```
public DataFrameWriter<T> partitionBy(scala.collection.Seq<String> colNames)
```

so if you want to partition data by `year` and `month` spark will save the data to folder like:

```
year=2016/month=01/
year=2016/month=02/
```

You have mentioned [`orc`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#orc(java.lang.String)) - you can use saving as a `orc` format with:

```
df.write.partitionBy('year', 'month').format("orc").save(path)
```

but you can easily insert into hive table like:

```
df.write.partitionBy('year', 'month').insertInto(String tableName)
```

**Getting all partitions:**

Spark sql is based on hive query language so you can use [`SHOW PARTITIONS`](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/04%20SQL,%20DataFrames%20%26%20Datasets/11%20SparkSQL%20Language%20Manual/Show%20Partitions.html) to get list of partitions in the specific table.

```
sparkSession.sql("SHOW PARTITIONS partitionedHiveTable")
```

Just make sure you have `.enableHiveSupport()` when you are creating session with **`SparkSessionBuilder`** and also make sure whether you have [`hive-conf.xml` etc.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables) configured properly

Comment: assuming I call `partitionBy()` twice for the same schema. Does spark smart enough to recognize that he can avoid this operation i.e assuming I had data like you mentioned and I would like to add ` year=2017/month=01` to my dataframe, does spark smart enough to recognize that he doesn't have to shuffle/load data from `year2016/month=1`?

Comment: `show partitions my_table` command is not giving me the location/path for the files on the hadoop file system.

Comment: @DavidH when you have a dataframe with `year 2017` and `month 01` and write these data in the table, spark will create this partition and store new data without loading data from `year2016/month=1`. i dont get your second comment. when you call [`show partitions my_table`](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/04%20SQL,%20DataFrames%20%26%20Datasets/11%20SparkSQL%20Language%20Manual/Show%20Partitions.html) and you have enabledhivesupport, spark sqlshould show list eg: `yearX/monthY` for partitioned `my_table`

Comment: see my **edit**. Are you sure that Full outer join is smart enough not to load all the table? if so it solving the problem

Comment: @DavidH If I understand correctly what you want - `df.write.partitionBy(...).mode(Overwrite).saveAsTable("my_table")` is OK. and I guess what you need - override only data in dataframe and keep other records without modification. Right? If so AFAIK it's not so easy and spark is not designed for this purpose rather analytics. What you can do to avoid FULL OUTER JOIN and rewriting all the table is drop selected partition and load the new one with your data after writing phase.

Comment: that's make sense. thanks for your help. btw do you have any snippest that I can look on? If I will find something I will post it as part of the solution

Answer (score 5):

In spark using scala, we can use the catalog to get partitions:

```
spark.catalog.listColumns(<databasename>, <tablename>)
.filter($"isPartition" === true)
.select($"name").collect()
```

Comment: This will only give the partition column names not the values itself.